# Problem with laser scan Hokuyo and windows/glass

Tags: slam, navigation, laser, scan, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I use a laser Hokuyo UTM-30LX. I use hector_slam in ROS hydro.
When I use my laser in a hallway with windows, hector_mapping create a false wall some meters behind to the windows.
In this video, I think that they removes this problem.
Video in youtube (I can´t publish links):
Handheld Mapping System: Schloss Dagstuhl New Building Dataset

Someone have a solution for this problem?
Thanks you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/124006/problem-with-laser-scan-hokuyo-and-windows/glass./) by [alex.filgueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/11401/alex.filgueira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2014-01-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For [the video you mention](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cfq3s4-H2S4) we didn't do any special filtering for reflective surfaces, but just let the system cope with the effects. Reflections are actually often reproducible and to the LIDAR/SLAM system things really look like there's "a room behind the mirror", with the "room" actually being used for scanmatching. It gets a little ugly if a robot tries to drive into this room of course (or if phantom obstacles are generated in otherwise free space). Actually detecting reflective/mirror surfaces reliably can be quite tricky and I don't know of a available open source solution for ROS for achieving that task. A classic advice would be "use another sensor with a different sensing modality" like a ultrasonic sensor. This can certainly help, but integrating that information with the rest of the software (SLAM as well as path planning) can be a non-trivial task.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2